# can i assign and send out coupon codes by query

Tags: query, dataextensions, campaign, sql

i have a campaign in which coupon codes should be emailed to new customers who are entered in a data extensions.

I already have a coupon data extension with code and IsClaim flag which is FALSE by default. I have another data extension that holds all the emails.

I not NOT looking to use AMPScript. Is there any way i can assign unique unclaimed coupon codes, email coupon code and make sure a subscriber DO NOT get coupon code more than once?

In marketing cloud SET does not work in query so how can I do this by using queries and automation only?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you can only issue coupon codes using AMPscript. If you use the default AMPscript code, a coupone will only be issued once to a subscriber.  If a subscriber is able to receive multiple coupons from the set of coupons, then an additional variable is necessary - like an Order ID